# Return values from an API in a JSON array

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

I have this website that calls data from the API, renders the data in a table but every single cell returns undefined.

The data in the API is inside an array like [] but the there are multiple data sets with {} inside them which I'm not sure how to define in JavaScript. How would I fix this?

[This is the link to the API](http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees) from where I wish to render the data.  Here is an example of this data:

```
[
    {
        "id": "40129",
        "employee_name": "EllakZa",
        "employee_salary": "56106",
        "employee_age": "311",
        "profile_image": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "40212",
        "employee_name": "Amit Negi111",
        "employee_salary": "123456",
        "employee_age": "44",
        "profile_image": ""
    }
]
```

My code follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees", function(data){
            var employeeData = '[]';
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function({key, value}){
                employeeData += '<tr>';
                employeeData += '<td>'+data.id+'</td>';
                employeeData += '<td>'+data.employee_name+'</td>';
                employeeData += '<td>'+data.employee_salary+'</td>';
                employeeData += '<td>'+data.employee_age+'</td>';
                employeeData += '<td>'+data.profile_image+'</td>';
                employeeData += '<tr>';
            });
            $('#tracerouteTable').append(employeeData);
        });
    });
```

Comment: can you show what the `console.log(data)` shows?

Comment: Why is `employeeData` initialized as a string containing `[]`?  Secondly, `data` is the collection; it isn't going to have `id` and other properties.  You seem to be ignoring `key` and `value` for some reason.

Comment: Not sure about `function({key, value})`

Comment: The console.log(data) displays all the arrays of data in order, employeeData has [] otherwise when I run the site the table doesn't show.

Comment: I followed a tutorial on how to do this code, I'm not sure what key and value are mean't to be doing. But if I remove them then it causes the same issue, the table doesn't show the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees", function(data){
            var employeeData = '';
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                employeeData += '<tr>';
                employeeData += '<td>'+value.id+'</td>';
                employeeData += '<td>'+value.employee_name+'</td>';
                employeeData += '<td>'+value.employee_salary+'</td>';
                employeeData += '<td>'+value.employee_age+'</td>';
                employeeData += '<td>'+value.profile_image+'</td>';
                employeeData += '<tr>';
            });
            $('#tracerouteTable').append(employeeData);
        });
    });
```

To know more about jquery each follow this [link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: @TaranBasi if it works perfectly, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

'data' is the the array returned from the api, so 'data.id' is undefined. You need to access the properties of each object within the array, so iterate over the array und use each item for accessing the properties.

use

```
data.forEach((item) => {
  employeeData += '<tr>';
  employeeData += '<td>'+item.id+'</td>';
  employeeData += '<td>'+item.employee_name+'</td>';
  employeeData += '<td>'+item.employee_salary+'</td>';
  employeeData += '<td>'+item.employee_age+'</td>';
  employeeData += '<td>'+item.profile_image+'</td>';
  employeeData += '<tr>';
});
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Data is an array of JSON objects. So in your code `key` is the index of the current JSON object and `value` is the current JSON object.

Access the data inside the JSON object like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees", function(data){   
    console.log(data);
    $.each(data, function({key, value}){
        var employeeData = '';

        employeeData += '<tr>';
        employeeData += '<td>' + value.id + '</td>';
        employeeData += '<td>' + value.employee_name + '</td>';
        employeeData += '<td>' + value.employee_salary + '</td>';
        employeeData += '<td>' + value.employee_age + '</td>';
        employeeData += '<td>' + value.profile_image + '</td>';
        employeeData += '<tr>';


        $('#tracerouteTable').append(employeeData);
    });
});
```