# Mesonet API JSON response to html table

Tags: jquery, json, api, html-table

I am trying to turn a JSON API response into a HTML table. I have a few of the pieces pulling in properly, but cannot figure out how to dig deeper into the response. I want to get the observation time, temperature, and wind gust/speed into the table. It does not like when I put another '.value' after any of the OBSERVATIONS requests. It just says 'value is undefined'. Any help is appreciated!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Alaskan Weather Observations</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <h1>Alaskan Weather Observations</h1>
            <br />

            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="station_table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Station Name</th>
                    <th>Station ID</th>
                    <th>Longitude</th>
                    <th>Latitude</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Temperature</th>
                    <th>Wind Speed</th>
                    <th>Wind Gust</th>
                </tr>               
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://api.mesowest.net/v2/stations/latest?",{
    state: "ak",
    vars: "air_temp,wind_speed,wind_gust",
    token: "token goes here"
    }, function(data){
        var station_data = '';
        for(var i=0;i<data.STATION.length;i++){
            station_data += '<tr>';
            station_data += '<td>'+data.STATION[i].NAME+'</td>';
            station_data += '<td>'+data.STATION[i].STID+'</td>';
            station_data += '<td>'+data.STATION[i].LONGITUDE+'</td>';
            station_data += '<td>'+data.STATION[i].LATITUDE+'</td>';
            station_data += '<td>'+data.STATION[i].OBSERVATIONS.air_temp_value_1.date_time+'</td>';
            station_data += '<td>'+data.STATION[i].OBSERVATIONS.air_temp_value_1+'</td>';
            station_data += '<td>'+data.STATION[i].OBSERVATIONS.wind_speed_value_1+'</td>';
            station_data += '<td>'+data.STATION[i].OBSERVATIONS.wind_gust_value_1+'</td>';
            station_data += '</tr>';
        };
        $('#station_table').append(station_data);
    });
    });     
    </script>
```

[what displays with my current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMFrl.png)
[Data I am trying to parse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lUYS.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57167844/return-values-from-an-api-in-a-json-array

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data so we can see how to address the issue

Comment: I just updated it with another image. There are a couple thousand stations that I want to scrape through, so I need it to run through and grab every station. I figured out the 'i' portion to run through the stations, but I feel like I am missing another variable somewhere to grab the specifics under 'OBSERVATIONS'.

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS I have already used that link to get to where I currently am. The problem is their coding doesn't account for the arrays within the array of stations I am trying to capture. Thanks for your help though!